# PyQt6 Label is not updating with every iteration of for loop

Tags: for-loop, user-interface, python-3.9, qtimer, pyqt6

I'm a beginner in programming and I have a problem making a label on my GUI to change its text value to inform the user of word's meaning (working on English dictionary). I would like the label to update itself with every loop, and so to show all the the definitions of a given word. However, the program only updates itself once the entire for loop is completed, and displays only the last definition of a word.

I've learned that I should use a QTimer, and tried it as it's shown in documentation, but with no success.

I would appreciate any help of how to make the label to update itself. Thank you.

Here is the code I am using:

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QMessageBox
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QLabel, QPushButton, QLineEdit, QComboBox, QScrollArea
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt, QTimer

import json
from difflib import get_close_matches


data = json.load(open("data.json"))

def translate(word):
    word = word.lower()
    if word in data:
        return data[word]
    elif word.title() in data:
        return data[word.title()]
    elif word.upper() in data:
        return data[word.upper()]
    elif len(get_close_matches(word, data.keys())) > 0:
        msg = QMessageBox()
        msg.setWindowTitle('Get close matches')
        msg.setText("Did you mean %s instead? Press Yes if yes, or No if no: " % get_close_matches(word, data.keys())[0])
        msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Icon.Question)
        msg.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.StandardButton.Yes | QMessageBox.StandardButton.No)
        msg.setDefaultButton(QMessageBox.StandardButton.Yes)
        ret = msg.exec()

        if ret == QMessageBox.StandardButton.Yes:
            return data[get_close_matches(word, data.keys())[0]]
        else: 
            return "We didn't understand your entry. Please double check it."
    else:
        return "The word doesn't exist. Please double check it."


def translate2():
    output = translate(text.text())
    if type(output) == list:
        i = 1
        for item in output:
            output_label.setText("%s. %s" % (i,item))
            i+=1
    else:
        output_label.setText(output)



app = QApplication([])
window = QWidget()
window.setWindowTitle('Word Definition')

layout = QVBoxLayout()

layout1 = QHBoxLayout()
layout.addLayout(layout1)

layout2 = QVBoxLayout()
layout.addLayout(layout2)

text = QLineEdit()
layout1.addWidget(text)

btn = QPushButton('Convert')
layout1.addWidget(btn, alignment=Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignBottom)
btn.clicked.connect(translate2)

output = QWidget()

output_label = QLabel('')
output_label.setFixedSize(600, 50)
layout2.addWidget(output_label)


window.setLayout(layout)
window.show()
app.exec()
```

Comment: But *how* do you expect it to update? Should they slowly "switch" between all results? And what if in the meantime the user presses the button again, and the words didn't finish their cycle?

Comment: As I learned,  a Qt GUI runs in an event loop of its own. However my for loop runs instead, and the GUI doesn't get CPU time and won't update between the executions of for loop. One possible solution is to use QThread. I somehow need to move the for loop to a secondary thread, while the GUI is happening in the main thread. Sorry if I didn't get your question correctly.

Comment: Sorry but you actually didn't answer any of my questions. For what we know, you may just need to delay the different texts by a certain amount of time, and that doesn't require threading at all, as a QTimer (along with a properly implemented function) will suffice.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Does it mean that I need to use QTimer inside the for loop to delay the iterations of for loop, so the main event loop can update?

Comment: No, since the for loop has to keep iterating, and using a timer in there could be potentially dangerous. As already said, I cannot provide any valid suggestion until you answer what asked above.

Comment: Right, I expect the main event loop to update after each iteration of for loop. As for the possibility of user presses the convert button while words didn't finish their cycle, I don't see a problem here - the new cycle will start right after the execution of the current one.

Comment: Or maybe I expect the QLabel's text to update immediately so that it's shown to the user, without waiting for the main event loop to be re-entered. I honestly have no idea. I just want it to be updated as it updates in the terminal if I write _print(i, item)_